# self.parentViewController logging UINavigationController, but acting like UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode4, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

Code:

```
- (IBAction)continueTouchHandler:(id)sender {
  RegistrationViewController *registration = [[RegistrationViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RegistrationView" bundle:nil];
  UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;  
  [navController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];

  [navController release]; 
  [registration release]; 
}
```

This is being called on a `UIButton` `TouchUpInside`.

`NSLog(@"%@", self.parentViewController)` *logs* a `UINavigationController` but without typecasting `self.parentViewController` as a `UINavigationController` I get the follow warning from `Xcode`:
`Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UINavigationController *' with an expression of type 'UIViewController *'`

I assume I get the warning because Xcode thinks `self.parentViewController` is a `UIViewController`. That's when I decided I need to "type cast" (i'm not to xcode / ios dev).

Strack trace before typecasting:

```
GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12 UTC 2011)
Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
GDB is free software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain conditions.
Type "show copying" to see the conditions.
There is absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
Attaching to process 99533.
Current language:  auto; currently objective-c
(gdb)
```

Stack trace after typecasting:

> GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1518) (Sat Feb 12 02:52:12
>   UTC 2011) Copyright 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc. GDB is free
>   software, covered by the GNU General Public License, and you are
>   welcome to change it and/or distribute copies of it under certain
>   conditions. Type "show copying" to see the conditions. There is
>   absolutely no warranty for GDB.  Type "show warranty" for details.
>   This GDB was configured as "x86_64-apple-darwin".sharedlibrary
>   apply-load-rules all Attaching to process 99324. 2011-10-08
>   14:27:52.593 Do You Like Me[99324:207] -[RegistrationViewController
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6833500 2011-10-08 14:27:52.596 Do You Like Me[99324:207]
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[RegistrationViewController
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x6833500'
>   *** Call stack at first throw: (  0   CoreFoundation                      0x00dc35a9 **exceptionPreprocess + 185  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x00f17313 objc_exception_throw + 44  2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00dc50bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187  3
>
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00d34966 __*forwarding*** + 966
>     4   CoreFoundation                      0x00d34522
>   _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50    5   UIKit                               0x001d22b7 -[UISectionRowData
>   refreshWithSection:tableView:tableViewRowData:] + 1834    6   UIKit
>   0x001cfd88 -[UITableViewRowData numberOfRows] + 108   7   UIKit
>   0x00083677 -[UITableView noteNumberOfRowsChanged] + 132   8   UIKit
>   0x00090708 -[UITableView reloadData] + 773    9   UIKit
>   0x0008d844 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 42     10  QuartzCore
>   0x016ada5a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 181   11  QuartzCore
>   0x016afddc CALayerLayoutIfNeeded + 220    12  QuartzCore
>   0x016550b4 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 310
>     13  QuartzCore                          0x01656294
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 292    14  QuartzCore                          0x0165646d
>   _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 99     15  CoreFoundation                      0x00da489b
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION** + 27    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00d396e7 __CFRunLoopDoObservers
>   + 295     17  CoreFoundation                      0x00d021d7 __CFRunLoopRun + 1575    18  CoreFoundation                      0x00d01840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208   19  CoreFoundation
>   0x00d01761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97    20  GraphicsServices
>   0x00ffb1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217  21  GraphicsServices
>   0x00ffb289 GSEventRun + 115   22  UIKit
>   0x00023c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160   23  Do You Like Me
>   0x00001fde main + 126     24  Do You Like Me
>   0x00001f55 start + 53 ) terminate called after throwing an instance of
>   'NSException' Current language:  auto; currently objective-c (gdb)

How should I go about getting past this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three things. First, use the `navigationController` property instead of `parentViewController`. So instead of this:

```
UINavigationController *navController = (UINavigationController *)self.parentViewController;  
[navController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];
```

do this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:registration animated:YES];
```

Second, don't send a `release` message to the navigation controller:

```
[navController release]; // Don't do this!
```

Third, the error message in the console gives a strong hint as to the nature of the problem:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
'-[RegistrationViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6833500
```

This means that the program crashed trying to send the message `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` to an instance of `RegistrationViewController`, so make sure that class has an implementation of the missing method. (Note: if you think it already does implement that method, double-check to make sure it's spelled correctly.)

Comment: Out of curiousity, why am I not releasing the navController? I'm still in awe that you came up with that so accurately. I get the answer, but it just goes to show that I have a lot to learn still. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jackson You're welcome. Manual reference counting with retain/release is a little complex. In order to understand when, and more importantly *why* you should (or shouldn't) send `release` or `autorelease` messages, read the object ownership rules documented in the iOS Memory Management Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html